# Upgrading Omnifaces - duplicates validator ID

Tags: jsf-2, jboss7.x, cdi, mojarra, omnifaces

I have a java ee 6 project bundled as ear-file that contains two web war-archive. Both using Omnifaces. Today I upgrade Omnifaces to the newest version 1.6. But now I cannot deploy anymore. I got the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Registering validator 'class org.omnifaces.validator.RequiredCheckboxValidator' failed, duplicates validator ID 'omnifaces.RequiredCheckboxValidator' of other validator 'class org.omnifaces.validator.RequiredCheckboxValidator'.
    at org.omnifaces.cdi.validator.ValidatorExtension.processValidators(ValidatorExtension.java:73)
...
```

My Envroiment:
JBoss AS 7.1.1/ Omnifaces 1.6/ JSF Mojarra 2.1.26/ Primefaces 3.5

THX in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that you've properly removed the old version and cleaned the server's work folder?

Comment: Yes. I have removed all the files from deployments/ tmp/ data directories.

Comment: Okay. It seems then that both WARs of same EAR are sharing the same CDI context.

Comment: I created an issue report: https://code.google.com/p/omnifaces/issues/detail?id=251

Comment: It is a CDI spec issue as it was not 100% clear how EAR deployments work, try with JBoss7.2 or WildFly which has newer version of Weld that somewhat addresses that.

Answer (score 0):

This bug has been fixed in 1.6.1. There's quite a story behind this bug, so I just wrote a blog on that: [CDI behaved unexpectedly in EAR, so OmniFaces 1.6.1 released!](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2013/10/cdi-behaved-unexpectedly-in-ear-so.html)

Summarized: CDI context isn't WAR-wide, but EAR-wide. As to the particular exception you faced, it's because there was only one CDI `ValidatorExtension` being loaded from one WAR which is then applied EAR-wide and thus processing all `@FacesValidator` classes from **both** WARs instead of the WAR where the CDI extension was being loaded from.

Note that this is not a problem in OmniFaces. This is a problem in the way how CDI works in EARs.